# Closing lid freezes laptop

Tags: 10.04, laptop

Closing the lid on my Dell Studio 15 which is running Ubuntu 10.04 freezes the screen. This is a new problem in Ubuntu 10.04 which did not exist in 9.10

I have tried playing with all the settings in System->Preferences->Screensaver but nothing seems to make any difference. (please note the Power Management settings are accessible from here so I have tried those too.)

I don't need hibernate or suspend. I just want to be able to close the lid, and then open it and still have a working laptop.

Is their a settings somewhere that will make Ubuntu ignore the lid closing?

Comment: Please file a bug re to it freezing, also explaining if you can reproduce this problem when suspending or hibernating.

Comment: If you disable all of hibernate, suspend and blank screen, I don't see what could make the laptop freeze... I assume you didn't install any non-default tools related to power-management? Can you reproduce this when running from a live-CD or live-USB?

Comment: the last one doesn't work if i'm working on battery power
Is their a solution for this?

Comment: I have the same problem with my laptop (Ubuntu 10.04 64bit; ATI Radeon HD 3430; HP Compaq 6730s). It is possible to move mouse pointer but it is not possible to change anything or select text on web page for example.

It is reproduced sometimes. Sometimes it is reproduced even if i'm working in a browser (surely this happens with google chrome; not sure about others).
The only quick solution is to activate another desktop with ctrl+alt+right and then return to previous desktop ctrl+alt+left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by changing to the closed source FLGRX driver.

Answer (score 2):

These settings are in System -> Preferences -> Power Management.

[image: power management]

Comment: actually this is the same screen as you get to when clicking on the Power Management settings from within the screen saver screen. And so I have already tried changing all these settings but it still freezes

Comment: It interesting to note that their is actually no 'do nothing' option for when laptop lid is closed so I have it set to Blank screen like in your screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is no SD card inserted.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1478787 has 120,000 views of 980 responses - it is still possible that one of the solutions will work for you.

http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/585765 is about the most useful bug report, although https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/528981 worked for me (mainline kernel 2.6.34 solution).

Comment: This is a good point to bring up, However it is not a solution for me as I have no SD cards inserted. I did spend quite some time reading and trying solutions from that thread before asking the question here.

Answer (score 1):

`gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-power-manager/buttons/lid_ac "nothing"`

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid

Comment: Has this command actually solved the problem?