# Freezes when I close the lid

Tags: 10.04, boot, dell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Closing lid freezes laptop ubuntu 10.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3179/closing-lid-freezes-laptop-ubuntu-10-04)

Hi,

Everytime I close my laptop lid, my laptop doesn't go into hibernate,suspand,blackscreen...
It just freezes, even when I open the lid, and the only thing left to do is restart my pc. I use a dualboot system, vista 64 and ubuntu 10.04 on a Dell Studio 15. Is there any way to fix this without messing up the vista partition?

Comment: Stupid fix: switch over to Kubuntu if you have this problem, and under kubuntu power management, set 'force lock'. This way, you can put your laptop in sleep before closing the lid and it starts up again (not without the 'force lock' option though...) But very silly there isn't an obvious solution for ubuntu, especially when they state that dell studio 15 is 'Ubuntu-certified' --'

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/q/3179/448

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried configuring what Ubuntu does when you close the lid? That's under System › Preferences › Power Management. Does the problem still occur if you set it to Blank Screen instead of Suspend? What if you use the session menu (power icon on the top right) and choose Suspend?

Of course, it shouldn't be freezing in the first place, but hopefully we can work around this. If you're interested, you can also file a bug report so developers can work on the issue directly.

Comment: doesn't help trust me I tried