# How can I tell Ubuntu to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?

Tags: power-management

I would like closing the laptop lid to be a no-op. How can I do that?

Comment: Found it hard to believe that there is no GUI setting for this.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/972177/724441 works for Ubuntu 17.10 with Gnome.

Answer (score 572, accepted):

#### For 13.10 - 24.04:

To disable Ubuntu doing anything closing the laptop lid:

1. Open the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file in a text editor as root, for example,

   ```
   sudoedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf
   ```
2. If `HandleLidSwitch` is not set to `ignore` then change it:

   ```
   HandleLidSwitch=ignore
   ```

   Make sure it's not commented out (it is commented out if it is preceded by the symbol `#`) or add it if it is missing.
3. Restart the systemd daemon (**be aware that this will log you off**) with this command:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind
   ```

   or from 15.04 onwards:

   ```
   sudo service systemd-logind restart
   ```

<sub>See also: [Ubuntu Server 13.10 now goes to sleep when closing laptop lid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360615/ubuntu-server-13-10-now-goes-to-sleep-when-closing-laptop-lid)</sub>

**For GNOME Users:**

If you are using GNOME (the default in 18.04+), then you can do this easily without changing system settings by using the "Gnome Tweak Tool". It can be installed from the Ubuntu Software Store (It is called GNOME Tweaks).  Or if you prefer the console:

```
# Ubuntu 18.04
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool

# Ubuntu 20.04+
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks
```

Run it after installing, then under *Power*, Turn off the setting to do nothing when lid is closed. I tested this on Ubuntu 18.04 and it works.

Comment: This didn't work for me. What finally solved it for me was setting `IgnoreLid=true` in `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf`

Comment: `HandleLidSwitch=hibernate` if you want your laptop to hibernate instead of doing nothing.

Comment: Aternative: sudo apt-get install dconf-tools, open dconf Editor application, go to org => gnome => setting-deamon => plugins => power

Comment: Worked for me on 14.04.

Comment: Confirmed:  Worked for me on Xubuntu 15.05 in both boot-to-console and boot-to-gui modes.

Comment: On Ubuntu 15.04, I got "restart: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused" from the systemd command.

Comment: @abrasadera's approach is the only one that works on the latest Ubuntu as of time of this comment.

Comment: Probably worth noting that THIS works, unlike the documentation, and obvious method of doing it through System Settings->Power.

Comment: I restart it using `sudo service systemd-logind restart`

Comment: This worked with Ubuntu MATE 14.04 (without gedit-part - with Ubuntu MATE you may wish to use pluma or nano), I only needed to uncomment and edit mentioned line. Now I can shut down my laptop without it going to sleep during shutdown, if lid is closed. This can easily happen when doing a hasty shutdown (closing lid too early) or when using external screen. Using gconf-editor had no help with the "sleep during shutdown"-problem, because different config hits in when control is switched off from userspace (at least with MATE).

@Tasos, why you use -H with this?

Comment: this works too on debian 8.4, jessie. I think that is good to know for some. However, restart the service by `sudo service systemd-logind restart`(@Kassius)

Comment: You should use gksudo and not sudo when opening a graphical app as root!

Comment: It works well on Ubuntu 16.04. Works as workaround for https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1566302 Lots of thanks!

Comment: Worked for Ubuntu 17.04 with Gnome as well

Comment: The solutions didn’t work for me on Ubuntu 17.04. Using @Kimble’s suggestion required calling `service upower restart` after changing `UPower.conf` and it worked.

Comment: from 15.04 onwards: sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind

Comment: For those who have LED keyboards, what command is for light up the keyboard again when laptop lid is open?

Comment: This worked for me on budgie-desktop 10.4 (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 64-bit).

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu Server 18.04.

Comment: Worked! Now I have a place to set my coffee. Xubuntu 18.04 on Dell laptop using dual 15" USB screens. The laptop screen is always blank anyway.

Comment: Worked on 19.10

Comment: Works for 18.04 32-Bit with a ssh-server installation too.

Comment: I want my computer to only blank my screen when I close the lid.

I set the  lid-close-[ac|battery]-action to "blank" in Gnome's dconf Editor.
Seems to work until I re-open lid. What happens then is that it takes 1 sec, then it locks my PC. Then it lags 1-5 more seconds, and suspends my PC. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: works welll on ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS 64bit desktop. 
gnome-tweak is easier for changing behavior.
log-off and log-in required to make effect.

Comment: ohh, I installed tweak and I forgot that app :) thank you

Comment: Work well for 20.04 64bit desktop. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The gnome tweak change did not alone work for me. The change that worked was with the Upower conf.

Comment: Is there a solution if you have gdm stopped on Ubuntu 20.04? I've tried all solutions above, and it works but only when gdm is running. When I close the lid after I stopped gdm my laptop goes into standby again instead of doing nothing (resp. turning the screen off..).

Comment: How do we prevent sleep, but still have the screen turn off with the lid closed?

Comment: Worked partially for me on Debian 11. I also had to set `HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore` to keep my laptop awake while it's connected to power.

Comment: Works perfectly on Ubuntu 22.04. Thanks for the fix mister, highly appreciated! Hope to see some GUI tool in future that handles this type of functionality, because this seem like a core configuration thing!

Comment: Thank you, it finally worked on 22.04. Not the gnome-tweaks solution, that only disables suspend when I'm logged in, not on the login screen.

Answer (score 74):

### For 11.04 and earlier:

**Do nothing when laptop lid is closed**  (helpful when an external monitor is connected):

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and enter this: `gconf-editor`
- apps > gnome-power-manager > buttons
- Set `lid_ac` and `lid_battery` to `nothing`

[image]

OR

1.When on AC Power, do nothing when laptop lid is closed:  
`gconftool-2 -t string -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/buttons/lid_ac nothing`

2.When on Battery Power, do nothing when laptop lid is closed:  
`gconftool-2 -t string -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/buttons/lid_battery nothing`

---

**Blank screen when laptop lid is closed**  (preferable when no external monitor is connected):

- System > Preferences > Power Management
- On AC Power (On Battery Power) > Actions
- When laptop lid is closed: Blank screen

[image]

OR

1.When on AC Power, blank screen when laptop lid is closed:  
`gconftool-2 -t string -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/buttons/lid_ac blank`

2.When on Battery Power, blank screen when laptop lid is closed:  
`gconftool-2 -t string -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/buttons/lid_battery blank`

Answer (score 71):

#### Ubuntu 15.10 - Ubuntu 20.04

**TL;DR**: Add `IgnoreLid=true` to `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf`

1. Open a terminal and run:

   ```
    sudoedit /etc/UPower/UPower.conf
   ```
2. Change `IgnoreLid` to `IgnoreLid=true`
3. Save and exit the editor.
4. Restart the UPower service with:

   ```
    service upower restart
   ```

Comment: For me, this didn't work on Ubuntu 15.10, but following these steps here did: http://askubuntu.com/a/594417

Comment: Perfect. This prevents my external monitor from going to sleep on lid close in 16.10. No more worries when closing it.

Comment: Works for 16.04 - Prevents networks from disconnecting, which is the single most important issue for me.  Thank you.

Comment: This didn't work on Ubuntu 17.10 with Gnome.

Comment: Work on 18.04 and 18.10. Thanks.

Comment: My Ubuntu Server 18.04 has no `/etc/UPower` directory. However, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/372616/247736) to this question worked.

Comment: For some strange reason (18.04), the accepted answer only partially worked. While the computer was able to continue running with the lid closed, it refused to turn off. Adding the change in this answer resolved the quirk. (I haven't checked if this answer on its own was all I needed).

Comment: I needed this to prevent external screen from sleeping.

Answer (score 43):

### For 11.10 - 12.04:

You can select "Do Nothing" in the power settings. Open the dash (super key), search for "power" and then select the correct option in the dropdown. Note that closing the lid will actually turn off the screen though plus any external monitors:

[image]

If you move the mouse then any connected monitors will power back up with the laptop closed. This will then become the primary monitor.

This might either have been removed at some point, or it requires some hardware support which is not available in all systems: [Since 16.04, I don't have 'when the lid is closed' options in power settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764194/since-16-04-i-dont-have-when-the-lid-is-closed-options-in-power-settings) as there have been reports that it was not visible on Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't seem to work. I think it's a bug in 12.04.

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

Comment: It is not working for me in Lubuntu 13.10

Comment: working for my ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Any way to do this on the command line?  No X server on my lucid machine...

Comment: Jeez amazing, moving the mouse was the "solution".. because Ubuntu refuses not to suspend when closing the lid.

Answer (score 7):

## 11.04 and previous versions

Copying 1st given answer from:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1319921&highlight=close+laptop+lid

In a terminal (Applications-->Accessories-->Terminal), type: gconf-editor

Navigate to apps-->gnome-power-manager-->buttons and set lid_ac and/or lid_battery to "nothing" (without the quotes).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I have **14.04.1 LTS, Trusty Tahr**.

What doesn't worked for me:

1. Open the /etc/systemd/logind.conf file in a text editor as root, for example,

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf
   ```

   Add a line `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` (make sure it's not commented out!),

   Restart the systemd daemon with this command:

   ```
   sudo restart systemd-logind
   ```
2. Edit gConf

   When on AC Power, do nothing when laptop lid is closed:

   ```
   gconftool-2 -t string -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/buttons/lid_ac nothing
   ```

   When on Battery Power, do nothing when laptop lid is closed:

   ```
   gconftool-2 -t string -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/buttons/lid_battery nothing
   ```

What worked for me:

Setting `IgnoreLid=true` in `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf`

Comment: Working at `Xubuntu 14.04.3 i386`. Xubuntu have utility `Power manager` but settings for closing lid not worked for me. This is registered bug?

Answer (score 6):

Let us create a script that works on all versions

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# PLEASE FEEL FREE TO CHANGE THE SCRIPT

# Ubuntu 16.04 [PLEASE COMPLETE]

sed -i '/HandleLidSwitch/d' /etc/systemd/logind.conf >/dev/null 1&>2
echo 'HandleLidSwitch=ignore' >> /etc/systemd/logind.conf >/dev/null 1&>2

# Ubuntu 14.04 [PLEASE COMPLETE]

sed -i '/IgnoreLid/d' /etc/UPower/UPower.conf >/dev/null 1&>2
echo 'IgnoreLid=true'>> /etc/UPower/UPower.conf

# [PLEASE COMPLETE ]

# gconftool-2 -t string -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/buttons/lid_ac [PLEASE COMPLETE ]
# gconftool-2 -t string -s /apps/gnome-power-manager/buttons/lid_battery nothing [PLEASE COMPLETE ]

# RESTART SERVICES

service upower restart
service systemd-logind restart
```

Comment: "HandleLidSwitch=nothing" does nothing useful. "HandleLidSwitch=ignore" is The Real Thing(tm).

Comment: +1 for trying to evolve a script here

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug with some laptops and monitors that makes Ubuntu not honor the "do nothing" setting when the laptop's lid is closed. I have not been able to find a complete solution, but maybe there is something to do with [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1875183.html) where they hint at this file : `/etc/default/acpi-support` and using:

```
gconftool-2 -t string /apps/gnome-power-manager/buttons/lid_ac -s "blank"
gconftool-2 -t string /apps/gnome-power-manager/buttons/lid_battery -s "blank"
```

Answer (score 3):

## For Saucy:

Edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and set `HandleLidSwitch=lock` to lock the screen on lid close (but not suspend), or `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` to not even lock the screen.

This is due to an upstream GNOME change. See [GNOME bug 687277](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687277) for the rationale for this change.

Comment: Does ubuntu use systemd?

Comment: systemd is now many things. Ubuntu does not use systemd's init ("pid 1"), but it does use components that were formerly independent but are now absorbed into the systemd source, such as udev. So you will see mentions of the systemd name on an Ubuntu system, but that does not mean that its init system has suddenly changed.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily **disable the lid lock feature** by clicking the **System Settings** icon in the Launcher/Task bar, and then clicking on **Brightness & Lock**.

From there, you flip the **Lock** switch to the off position, and un-check the "**Require my password when wakening from suspend.**" check-box.

[image]

**Another thing you have to watch for if you also plan on setting up hibernation (suspend-to-disk) is whether or not your system has a large enough swap partition to actually go into hibernation**.  Hibernation is different than suspend, but sometimes people like to set up the hibernation feature while they are configuring suspend.

You can also go over your **Power** settings, so they don't suspend the system when the lid is close.  You can do this in **System Setting -> Power**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## 11.04 and previous versions

you can also go to `system->preferences->power management`

near bottom of the window you will find a dropdown where you can select what your system does when lid is closed

Answer (score 2):

## 12.04

In System Settings, open Brightness & Lock.  On that page, uncheck the checkbox at the bottom that says, "Require my password when waking from suspend."

Comment: Tried this and it made no difference.

Answer (score 2):

I like to suspend my laptop sometimes, and other times I like to keep it going for long times like a server (do nothing when I close the lid).  I use Debian, and here's my simple script to do either one on the fly without rebooting:

```
# run this in the as the same user (or root) that xwindow is using

# test for required parameter --> empty not allowed
if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
    echo "Please provide true or false"
    echo "True means keep running when lid is closed"
    echo "False means suspend the computer when lid is closed"
    exit;
fi

# "running true" means keep running even if the lid is closed
if [ "$1" = "true" ]; then
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action nothing
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action nothing
fi


# "running false" means suspend the computer!
if [ "$1" = "false" ]; then
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action suspend
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action suspend
fi

# if "echo" is supplied as a param, just show the current settings
if [ "$1" = "echo" ]; then
    gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action
    gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 
fi

# restart gnome to make changes effective
/etc/init.d/gdm3 restart
```

Comment: Worth noticing that this method using `gsettings` is the only one (I can see) that does not require `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

## For 12.10:

Edit `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` and add `IgnoreLid=true` to the bottom.

This method no longer works in Saucy. I am unsure about 13.04.

Comment: Works on 15.04 64 bit after issuing `systemctl restart upower`.

Comment: /etc/UPower/Upower.conf IgnoreLid=true on ubuntu 14.04 use to work. after the 3.13 kernel roll out it not longer works anymore

Answer (score 0):

So... I tried all the possible solutions listed here, still had the problem. But it turned out to a pretty silly reason.

Well, I wonder why the answerers here didn't mention the part. It's a very basic Linux trick **uncommenting** is. But hey sometimes there could be some human error because we're not a scripting language or something, right??

So, do the following.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

Change the `#HandleLidSwitch=suspend` part to

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

So the change is as follows.

```
- #HandleLidSwitch=suspend
+ HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

Answer (score 0):

*Adding an solution not previously listed:*

For me, I want my laptop to stay on, but only when it's on A/C or docked. If there's no external power, I want the laptop to suspend as expected when the lid is shut. So my solution (Ubuntu 20.04 and newer) was as follows:

- Create the add-in confdir for logind config (via [manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/logind.conf.html)), and edit the add-in config `no-suspend-on-ac.conf`:

```shell
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/logind.conf.d && \
    sudoedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf.d/no-suspend-on-ac.conf
```

- Contents of `no-suspend-on-ac.conf`

```
[Login]
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
```

`HandleLidSwitch` remains at it's default behaviour, but with external power (direct or via a dock), shutting the lid will be ignored.