# How to close lid without triggering standby one time only

Tags: power-management

*Related: [How can I tell Ubuntu to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid)*

I have my laptop set to activate standby when I close the lid. I want to keep this as the default for both battery and AC power.

But occasionally I want to close the lid without triggering standby (eg. while just  listening to audio).

Is there someway I can tell Ubuntu, "I'm going to close the lid now. Don't stand by this time", without altering the defaults (because I almost always forget to change them back).

Answer (score 2):

Use the applet for surpressing the sleep mode. Right click onto the panel and than click "Add to panel..." The applet has a name like "applet to surpress sleep mode". Now you see a little clock on your panel. If you click it, it get'ss stroked out and your computer won't enter sleep mode anymore till you click it again.

Comment: is there a way to do the same in Unity?

Comment: Looks like it's called **Inhibit Applet**. Unfortunately it appears not to disable standby when I close the lid. Perhaps it only works for standby triggered by a period of inactivity (hence the clock icon).

Comment: There's a [pending bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-power/+bug/389857) from 2009 noting that the applet should disable standby on lid close, but doesn't.

Comment: Then you have to trigger the energy settings somehow, but I've relly no idea.

Comment: The `pm-powersave` package handles that. I've done some exploration of `pm-powersave`, but I don't see an easy answer for you.    See my answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/65632/why-is-wireless-down-strange-after-switching-to-battery