# Monitor switching when closing the lid of notebook

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, xrandr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell Ubuntu to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid)

In the office I use my notebook with an external 22" monitor. So I don't need the notebooks lcd and I would like to simply close the lid. But everytime I do this Ubuntu switches the resolution. How can I avoid this?

Comment: What graphic card do you have? It depends on the card, which tool you can use.

Comment: Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 4500MHD (Thinkpad SL 300)

Comment: Try this answer to see if it helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid/15531#15531

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Justis in the commets section:

> Try this answer to see if it helps: [How can I tell Ubuntu to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid/15531#15531)

This will probably be  your best answer