# When I close my Laptop lid my external monitor turns off

Tags: 11.10, laptop, monitor, lid

I saw this thread : [Prevent external monitors from shutting off when laptop lid is closed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45026/prevent-external-monitors-from-shutting-off-when-laptop-lid-is-closed)

I entered this code (from that thread): 
gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/gnome-power-manager/buttons/lid_ac "nothing"

But my external monitor still turns off when I close the lid.The laptop remains switched on regardless of the position of the lid. How do I get my external monitor to stay on when my laptop lid is closed?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid

I had faced the same issue... try this ...it works....

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in 11.10. I have resolved it by upgrading kernel to 3.2, but I would not recommend it since the upgrade might cause all sorts of problems.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/766490