# When i use gconf-editor to look for apps-->gnome-power-manager that key does not appear

Tags: 11.10, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell Ubuntu to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid)

I am using 11.10 and I am trying to set it up so I can close the lid on a laptop and my external monitor stay on. I am new to ubuntu so please be specific.

Answer (score 2):

Open System Settings and go to "Power"
and change when lid is closed to "do nothing"

see screenshot:[image]

BTW, the power settings are now stored in dconf, that means you would have to use dconf-editor and go to org/gnome/settings/daemon/plugins/power to change the settings.  However, that wouldn't make any difference in your case.

Comment: I tried that, I thought you would have to set the apps –> gnome-power-manager –> buttons. Then right-click ‘lid_ac’ and ‘lic_battery’ also

Answer (score 1):

GConf is being replaced with DConf. Install http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools and then run donf-editor. You'll find what you're looking for in /org/gnome/power-manager. Things are currently a mess in the Gnome world because of all these changes. Config is the biggest mess of all. Hopefully, things will begin to calm down and settle soon.

Comment: Location was org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/lid-close-ac-action. It was already set to nothing but when i close the lid it still blanks the external screen.

Comment: Interesting. Please file a bug? There are lots of minor issues to fix.

Comment: @user35475 make sure your run the dconf-editor as the user and not root.

Comment: @redsonic: That's a nice catch, although perhaps a couple of years late :)