# How to keep SSH server running with laptop lid closed

Tags: 10.10, server, ssh, power-management

I've changed the power management settings on my Ubuntu 10.10 server laptop to keep running with the lid closed but I loose any attempts to connect to it by ssh.

Is there a way to change this so that it will always be running?

P.S: It works perfectly with the lid open...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have all your power management settings in the OS right, it could be a setting in the BIOS that kills particular devices when the lid is closed.  I would check that first.

If you wanted to see that, you could run an infinite ping command in terminal and check wireshark output on the device your pinging for ICMP traffic.

Comment: I figured it out: I had to do it manually using gconf-editor.

([source](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid))

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is to edit the `logind.conf` file. From the Terminal, do this:

1. Open the `logind.conf` file:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf
   ```
2. Find and uncomment the line:

   ```
   #HandleLidSwitch=suspend
   ```

   So that it looks like this:

   ```
   HandleLidSwitch=ignore
   ```
3. Save the file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd> if you're using `nano`)
4. Reboot

[Source](https://amalgjose.com/2018/05/30/disable-sleep-mode-in-centos7-rhel7-laptop-on-lid-close-from-command-line/)

Comment: Same worked for other Linux distributive, just don't forget about the root rights for text editor when editing the logind.conf file.