# How can I avoid Ubuntu from asking for a password after the laptop's lid is opened after closed

Tags: 12.04, laptop, password

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell Ubuntu to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid)

Dear lovely ubuntu users,

when i close the lid of my laptop down, and then open it, it asks for a password. obviously I know it, but i do not want that any more. I am also getting used to 12.04 so some help would be much appreciated!