# Keep External HDMI Monitor ON

Tags: 12.04, power-management, hdmi, external-monitor, xbmc

I am running XBMC (Frodo) on an Asus U47A laptop (Intel Sandybridge graphics) with Ubuntu 12.04.  The laptop is connected to an older Phillips 27" tube HDTV via HDMI.  What I would like is for XBMC to stay running, and appear when I turn on my TV.  What actually happens is that when I turn off my TV, the HDMI signal stops and doesn't resume when the TV is turned back on.  To re-enable the signal, I've got to open the laptop lid which re-enables the laptop screen, and I guess figures out that the TV is there and turns it on as well - but rearranges my windows, so XMBC isn't where it was.  Alternately, I can unplug and replug the HDMI, but that's annoying too.

I know that the TV is older, but the functionality I expect worked fine when running XBMC on an old MacBook, so I know it *can* work.

I've tried for about a week so far, with no luck.  Obviously I've tried setting the lid actions to 'nothing' in the settings.  I've tried disabling the lid switch (as per [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145342/disabling-monitor-reconfiguration-when-closing-lid)) hoping to keep Ubuntu from disabling the laptop monitor and rearranging everything - but no luck. Shutting the lid still reconfigures the monitors.  I've tried various combinations of gconf, dconf and settings to force Ubuntu to keep the HDMI on.  I've tried to disable DMPS (as per [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61291/how-to-permanently-disable-monitor-power-saver-using-the-command-line)) in hopes of preventing the sleep in the first place.

I've even logged the callbacks via [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469828/how-to-create-a-callback-for-monitor-plugged-on-an-intel-graphics) to see if I can detect a signal when the TV is powered on. I do not get any callbacks when the TV goes off or on.  I have had marginal success reactivating the TV after it's been powered on by sending the command `xset dmps force off`, which blanks both screens, then when the mouse is moved or a key pressed the TV wakes. Sending `xset dmps force on` does NOT wake up the TV - it has to go off and back on.  However, those commands re-enables DMPS, which I've tried to turn *off*, so I don't think it's a solution either.

Another item of interest is that when I do the `xset dmps force off`, a `xset -q` shows "DMPS ON, Monitor ON".  But when I do a `xset -dmps` to turn it off, the -q shows "DMPS OFF" and doesn't mention the monitor state at all.

In the end, it would be nice if Ubuntu did NOT alter the HDMI signal at all - sending continuously. I would like to leave the laptop lid shut, and the HDMI signal to be going when I turn the TV on.  I'm not a long-term Linux user, but I'm willing to try just about anything to get this to work!

Thanks!

Comment: [Answer on a question about HDMI on second monitor, might help you][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/150749/ubuntu-12-04-do-nothing-when-lid-closed-blanks-out-external-monitor/160122#160122

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't the same sort of issue I'm having.  Closing the lid has no effect as expected.  The issue is when the TV is turned off, the HDMI signal stops and will not resume until I unplug and replug the HDMI cable, or force the DMPS off and then back on.