# System blacks out when resuming on opening lid

Tags: kernel, suspend

It is happening now and then but frequently these days. My system E420 Lenovo Thinkpad running 12.04 LTS blacks out and doesn't respond when woke up from sleep by opening the lid.

I then have to forcibly press the Start button and restart the entire system which is creating a headache for me.

Please suggest a way to overcome this problem. Main characteristics leading to this that I have noticed are:

- When a *video is paused* before I suspend the system
- When *Eclipse* or *pgAdmin* is running before suspending the system

Comment: Could it be a memory issue?. How much memory do you have? Which is your swap size?

Comment: No i don't think so .. 4GB RAM and 4881404 kB is the swap size

Comment: Does it happen when you login with gnome-fallback mode (metacity as the window manager)?

Comment: I have the same problem. Not frequently, but often enough to be problematic. In my case, I can see the cursor, and I can see that the underlying system is responsive, eg the cursor changes when I hover on where the password entry from the screenlock should be, I can unlock the screen and blindly type commands. I have a brand new Thinkpad X230 with 12GB of memory.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 4):

Hi I had this problem on my E420 Lenovo Thinkpad. The best solution I could find was to just disable suspend when the lid is closed. Its not a solution I know but it will make it a lot less annoying!

- [How can I tell Ubuntu to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your Lenevo uses an ATI graphics card. Although I am not certain that it is the graphics card that is causing your problem, the following may be useful reading in order of listing.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/391628

Unity does not start after installing the fglrx drivers on 12.10

I hope this goes some way in assisting you. At your own risk.