# monitor won't stay on if I close the lid

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I can't get the external monitor to stay on if I close my laptop's lid. I have been using Ubuntu since 12.04 and I have always had the same problem. Can anyone help? Thx.

Comment: What about: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I hope you know you could continue running process even though your monitor is switched off.

Answer (score 0):

closing the lid of the laptop puts it into standby. you can change this behavior in power settings. if you change it to "do nothing", then your external monitor will remain on.

[image: power settings in ubuntu]