# Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS suspends when 12.04 LTS did not

Tags: 14.04, suspend, ubuntu-netbook

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS Server on an Asus Eee PC netbook.

Back when I had 12.04 installed, I was able to close the netbook and the system would stay running. Now with 14.04, closing the netbook puts the system in suspend mode.

How do I make it so that the netbook stays powered on after closing the screen?

I have tried adding `acpi=off apm=off` to the default grub boot option in `/etc/default/grub`, but this did not work.

Comment: See if this fixes your problem

http://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid

Answer (score 1):

Per Alex-J's suggestion, using this link fixed the problem:
[How can I tell Ubuntu to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid)

Verified working on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS Server.

> To make Ubuntu do nothing when laptop lid is closed:
>
> 1. Open the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file in a text editor as root, for example,
>
>    `sudo -H gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf`
> 2. Add a line `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` (make sure it's not commented out!),
> 3. Restart the systemd daemon with this command:
>
>    `sudo restart systemd-logind`