# How can I tell Ubuntu 14.10 to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?

Tags: 14.10, laptop, suspend, power-management, lid

The issue is solved temporary using the method in this forum, but only if I have fresh boot, if i suspend my laptop and wake it again, Ubuntu will ignore my rules, and suspend when i close the lid.

[How can I tell Ubuntu to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid)

Comment: Go to System settings -->Power `When the lid is closed`in a drop down menu choose `do nothing`

Answer (score 2):

Go to the system settings and then click on `Power`. On that menu, you can configure the closed lid behavior.

[image: Power]

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Type `Power`
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. After opening find "*When the lid is closed*"
5. Select "*Do Nothing*"

That's it.

Comment: Hi Renish; please only link to your site in your profile. We avoid answer sign-offs here, including "Thank you" and personal contact details