# To close laptop lid without doing anything

Tags: lid

how to close my laptop lid in ubuntu 18.04.2 without doing anything?
i tried sudoedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf and also sudoedit /etc/UPower/UPower.conf

Comment: Do you mean https://askubuntu.com/questions/597595/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-14-10-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid?rq=1  ?

Answer (score 2):

To have the lid closed ***without doing anything:***

1. Have someone else close the lid for you.
2. execute the following commands:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xrandr default-monitors-setup 'follow-lid'
   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor false
   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'nothing'
   gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'nothing'
   ```

Now when that other person closes the lid for you, Ubuntu will not do anything neither!

### ;-)