# Keep notebook screen on when lid closed

Tags: 16.04, laptop, lenovo

I have a Lenovo P70 running Ubuntu 16.04. I want to keep the notebook screen ON when the lid is closed. Currently, when I close the lid to the notebook, the notebook display turns off. I have an external monitor still and all that is working fine, but I want to the laptop screen to remain ON even when the lid is fully closed. Note this is not an issue with the system going into suspend when the lid is closed; I already have all that disabled. How can I accomplish this?

So far I have tried things such as UPower.conf and logind.conf settings: https://askubuntu.com/a/742662

I have also run `xset dpms force on` when the lid is closed, but the notebook screen does not turn on.

For the curious, I am wanting this because this notebook has a built in colorimeter and is apparently designed to run with the lid closed but the notebook screen still physically on.

Comment: Not really. Obviously I want to be able to toggle this on and off and only enable this behavior when I am calibrating the screen color profile. Keeping the screen on with the lid closed for up to an hour or so is how the notebook is designed to function in this case.