# Make video player to keep playing when lid is closed

Tags: suspend, power-management, vlc, video-player

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I want my pc to stay on and allow music or movie in my players (either Ubuntu's default player or VLC media player) to keep playing when the lid is closed. I want this to occur only when the lid is closed while any of the players are running.

Please, note that this is different from [Keep notebook screen on when lid closed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/780613/keep-notebook-screen-on-when-lid-closed).

I have also read other related questions and their 'answers' but none of them really address my requirements. What do I do to achieve what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Go to System Settings and Power

Change the option When the lid is closed to Do nothing

Make sure that you changed the both on battery power and Plugged in to Do nothing


Thanks