# Play music even if the computer is closed

Tags: lock-screen

My problem is very simple : with my previous laptop I was able to play music even if the laptop was closed. Now I changed and everytime I'm closing it, the music turn off few seconds after. It is possible to fix it ? 
I tried to go to "Brightness and Lock" but nothing I tried work. 
Many thanks in advance !

Edit : I tried HandleLidSwitch=ignore, IgnoreLid=true, dconf and it didn't work. Also I tried the Power setting but I don't have any lid option on it : 
[image]

Comment: Perhaps this might be helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid

Comment: Thanks, I did try it, I'll restart my computer and tell you if it did work !

Comment: It did not work for me, but I did install dconf and finally it worked. Thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by installing **gnome-tweak-tool.**
Once installed just go to power and turn off suspend when laptop lid is closed.

Answer (score 0):

The comment to your question has a link recommending using systemd's `#HandleLidSwitch=suspend` feature. However on my system (Ubuntu 16.04) this feature was disabled by the `#` at the beginning of the line. Ubuntu was handling Lid Close operations directly and circumventing systemd.

When you went into "Settings" you went to the "Brightness & Lock" screen but if you go to the "Power" screen instead you will see this:

[image: Power do nothing on lid close]

As in the screen above, set `When the lid is closed` to `Do Nothing` and that is exactly what Ubuntu does when you close the lid, ie your music continues playing as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I tried HandleLidSwitch=ignore,  IgnoreLid=true and it didn't work. I'm also on 16.04.  My power setting is less complete than yours and I don't have the lid option (I edited my question). Also dconf didn't work. If you have any other ideas ... ^^

Comment: @N.H. You can answer your own question if you found a solution.