# Completely disable suspension/sleep in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, suspend, power-management

I'm trying to use my laptop as my alarm so I did the below settings to prevent suspension. However when I tried closing and opening my laptop lid after a few seconds, it didn't suspend.

[image: Settings 1]

[image: Settings 2]

Feeling satisfied, I closed my laptop lid and went to bed, but the alarm didn't ring the next morning and the laptop got suspended for some reason.

What am I doing wrong here? Are there any settings I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try to make two more changes, one of them or both of them:

1) Setting IgnoreLid=true in /etc/UPower/UPower.conf

Found here: [How can I tell Ubuntu to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid)

2) I had a different problem in 16.04 LTS with a laptop lid as well. I could not boot with the lid closed and was suspended.

I solved it by going to /etc/systemd/logind.conf and doing two steps:

a) Removed "#" from HandleLidSwitch, in order to activate it and

b) put "=ignore at the end

HandleLidSwitch=ignore

You will also found the second step at the same link as the first one. Hope they will help.

But, buying an alaram would not be a bad idea, because laptops is not a good idea to be turned on all day (the hours you sleep and the hours you may use it. At least buy a laptop cooling pad. They are not very expensive. And also an online UPS, but remove the laptop battery first.