# 'Do Nothing' on Lid Close doesn't work on 16.10

Tags: power-management, 16.10, lid

I am taking experience from using my Linux machine and recently I'm trying to work with the machine as I directed the display to my FHD monitor.(However my VGA controller has issues with FHD so I'm using it on 1440x900 60Hz instead of 1920x1080 60Hz)

I'm trying to close my notebooks lid to work on Monitor. These steps are what I tried so far.

1. Under System Settings I closed suspend or hibernate settings from
   Power and Brightness
2. As [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid) topic suggest I edited my logind.conf and made`HandleLidSwitch=ignore`(and it is not commented)
3. As another comment suggested, I installed Dconf-Editor and make all
   settings "Do Nothing" under org => gnome => setting-deamon =>
   plugins => power

Yet I couldn't find a solution. Can someone direct me to the solution?

Here are my settings:
[image]
[image]
[image]

## Edit:

The Output of Gsettings:
[image]

Comment: We need to check three settings. could you post the output of:  1. `gsettings get  org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action`, 2. `gsettings get  org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action` and 3.  `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor`. The latter might be the key, since I don't see it mentioned in your question.

Comment: @JacobVlijm updated

Comment: Shoot, I didn't see that one coming :(. Was hoping for nr.3

Comment: @JacobVlijm I realized that after I close the lid, external monitor disconnects the display, but the machine doesn't shutdown, It only stop displaying on external monitor.

Comment: Just fooling around, but what happens if you attach an external keybord, press (carefully, make no typos) Ctrl+Alt+T, and subsequently `xset dpms force on` + Return? If we can't fix it, maybe we can work around it. If it works, we can tune it and automate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55207/discussion-between-jacob-vlijm-and-egrimo).

Comment: @JacobVlijm I wrote the command from my external keyboard(Currently I am using computer with external mouse and keyboard) and no output return. Tried closing lid and second monitor still disconnects display.

Comment: Nono, *first* close the lid, *then* openh a terminal and run your command (blindly, with the lid closed)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Funny thing is all I needed was pressing a key in the keyboard after I close the lid. Problem is solved in a kinda funny way.

Comment: That is weird. How can we put an answer to this question? I guess you can best answer it yourself then :) We *can* automate it though, but probably not needed.

Comment: It is rude to post screenshots of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, the problem can be easily solve for me to press any key on external keyboard after screen goes off. Thanks Jacob Vlijm to direct me this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS: (I was rebooting instead of restarting the service which kept the changes form working.)

```
sudo vi /etc/default/acpi-support # and then set SUSPEND_METHODS="none"
sudo /etc/init.d/acpid restart
```