# Why is my external monitor put to sleep on lid close?

Tags: external-monitor, lid

I just edited `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to ignore lid close, as opposed to suspend, which seems to have worked. But now when I close the lid my external monitor goes to sleep. The system is still running though - if I move the mouse the monitor wakes up immediately.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What have you changed in `logind.conf`?

Comment: check this [Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid)

Comment: @Yaron I added `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` and 
`HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore` as per the top answer in your link. I shouldn't have stopped there -- three answers down there was another solution that fixed my monitor problem. Thanks! http://askubuntu.com/a/742662/428527

Comment: happy that it helped you solve the problem!