# Laptop won't get in sleep if I close the lid

Tags: suspend, thinkpad, lid

Recently I installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my ThinkPad T530.But I have a problem (and I know how much ThinkPad hardware is supported on the linux world).So If I close the lid,the thing won't get on sleep mode.I'm worried because it might be a hardware problem.So my questions are:

1.Did somebody tested Ubuntu on a T530/T430 and does the auto sleep when close the lid?

2.How can I fix it?
I already tried to change /etc/systemd/logind.conf

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: I have a Vanilla Ubuntu with Gnome

Comment: Use dconf-editor to check /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/.. lid-close-ac-action and lid-close-battery-action. These should both be suspend by default, but you never know.

Comment: Glad it worked out. I made an answer. Please accept when you have a chance.

Comment: This answer solved my problem. I hope it works for you too https://askubuntu.com/questions/972169/ubuntu-17-10-dont-suspend-when-lid-is-closed-just-lock-screen

Answer (score 2):

Use `dconf-editor` to change the settings:

```
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/lid-close-ac-action
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/lid-close-battery-action
```

to `'suspend'` (Note: the single quotes are required in the setting.)

In a default Ubuntu install, these would be set to `'suspend'` by default, but the vanilla desktop does not apparently do that.