# suspended overheating problem on DELL G5 15 5590; 18.04 bionic - best way to proceed?

Tags: 18.04, suspend, overheating

I recently (~10 d) got such a device to do some number crunching:

**DELL G5 15 5590**

it came with a respectable nvidia GPU, but a Win10 pre-install which didn't bother me.
linux is *not officially supported as shipping OS* for this device, but I thought that it should be no problem, since DELL seems to have shown good will wrt. linux on their hardware in the past.

after recovery image generation, the SDD was wiped and *bionic LTS 18.04.4 installed*. apart from minor problems, this worked quite nicely (apart from some boot hiccup messages, I still have to research for).

**however:** when sending the device to suspend with a full battery recently, and later (+2h) turning it back on, I found the **laptop to have gotten really hot**, fans spinning up like mad, providing a hot flow of air into my hands, while the battery was down to < 10%

it seemed like this would *potentially be hardware-degrading* behavior, if not hazardous.

**Questions:**

1. how do I best proceed to find out what might have caused this problem?
2. what might cause such an overheating when the machine should be suspended state?
3. am I wrong to ask such a question here?

thanks!

Comment: How are you suspending the laptop? eg closing lid, pressing power button, menu, command line, etc.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix as far as I remember, I closed the lid, but had checked some time before (in the course of the installation) if lid-closing really effects a suspend state. meaning, when I opened the lid, I had to push the power button to have it come back to life. given the *very* sparse status leds on this device sometimes still leaves you wondering.

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/972169/ubuntu-17-10-and-later-dont-suspend-when-lid-is-closed-just-lock-screen

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

1. You have to use: Dell Power Manager
   2.Thermal settings : Optimized
2. You can change-> Battery information->Settings->between 50% to 85%.

Comment: Is there a "Dell Power Manager" for Ubuntu or it is a Windows solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have this laptop, and by no means am expert or anything. But if you are having issues with heating and fans going up first and the most simple thing to do is to go to BIOS by pressing F12 at start up > Performance > Intel turbo boost and disable this **** into oblivion. At one point my temperatures were going to 95-98, with fans at 100 % or close to it, with boost disabled 60-70 with no performance change that I can see. I actually repasted it before and that haven't changed behavior too much, there are also some other known problems like changing power setting in My Dell app > Power > Thermal. Hope it helps, gl guys.