# Close lid without suspend

Tags: 20.04, login-screen, lid

How can you make it so when the laptop lid is closed, the PC doesn't suspend or lock but just turn off the display so that I don't have to log back in. I have tried changing the lid close action to blank but it logs me out. Also how do I set screen to "Blank" when lid is closed correctly? Doing it from dconf-editor doesn't seem to work!

Comment: Does this work? https://askubuntu.com/a/972177/480481

Comment: @pomsky That doesn't turn off my display at all. 1st thing I tried.

Comment: Turning the display off *and* not suspending / locking would probably be hard to achieve.

Comment: @pomsky It is quite easy to achieve in windows though. So why not in Ubuntu? Basically what I want is blank without logout.

Comment: That's kinda irrelevant, Ubuntu is not a like-for-like replacement of Windows.

Comment: I know but this should be possible. Isn't there a way to skip the login screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright. Found an answer. Put the screen to go blank when lid is closed. Then go to settings -> Privacy -> Screen Lock and turn off automatic screen lock.

Comment: How do you set the screen to go blank when the lid is closed? That's the main question, isn't it? There isn't an option for that in Settings or Tweaks. There's something in Dconf Editor but that doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 'blank' use action 'lock'. It will lock you out but wifi and all background process will be intact and will not make any delay as happens in  suspend.

Comment: Wait so what is the difference between blank, suspend and lock?