# Lenovo legion slim 5 shuts down when lid closed

Tags: drivers, 22.04, lenovo, shutdown, lid

I use Ubuntu 22.04.4 on Lenovo legion slim 5 16APH8. I would like to have my laptop go in suspend mode when I close the lid. But I have a problem:
When I close the lid of the laptop, there is always a chance that the laptop completely shuts down.

It happens even though I activated in Gnome tweaks the function to go to suspend mode when the lid is closed.

Most of the time when I close the lid the laptop goes in suspend mode. But it is not 100% reliable sometimes it shuts down.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What about if `LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no` is commented out like `#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no` Also, have you tried using [dconf editor](https://askubuntu.com/a/1020476/1671150)?

Comment: Also, are all the acpi support packages installed? `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt install acpi acpi-support acpica-tools acpid`

Comment: Hi, the problem happens even with  LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no commented out. I tried dfonf editor but the problem remains!

Comment: I installed acpi support packages as you told me but the problem remains.

Comment: Okay, I was actually kind of focusing on your other question about completely disabling it. Have you messed with `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf` yet? Remember, any changes made to systemd conf files might require a reboot to apply the changes.

Comment: Also, does this seem to happen after a certain period of time or is it just random like you might close the lid and after 30 seconds and then it shuts down sometimes but other times not?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I simplified my original post because I felt it was going in to many directions.

Comment: I uncommented `AllowSuspend=yes` in `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf`  but it does not seem to solve the problem.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to happen at a certain time. It is not more likely directly after a boot or after a long period of use. Also the computer shuts down directly when I close the lid. Not a certain time after having closed the lid.