# xfce laptop-server sleeps after reboot instead of starting ssh

Tags: ssh, login, suspend, power-management, xfce

I'm using my xfce laptop as a home server, but whenever I reboot it I have to go physically open the lid and log in. After that my power config settings kick in and I can close the lid again. Any way to keep it from ever suspending?

This had no effect: https://askubuntu.com/a/372616/39599

Comment: Did you also try the very first comment of that answer?  What version of Xubuntu are you using?  That first comment was also written here https://askubuntu.com/a/742662/231142

Comment: I did, no change. The xfcd is a fresh 16.04 install

Comment: Have you looked here at the bottom of the page about the line for the lid-switch?  https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/faq

Comment: Oh that looks promising. I'll try that out this evening after work, thanks!