# Configure closing the lid to suspend the laptop when an external monitor is used

Tags: 20.04, suspend, laptop, external-monitor, lid

When I use an external monitor the laptop does not automatically suspend when I close the lid. Instead the external monitor is then still in use.

I want to configure ubuntu in such a way that the laptop always suspends when I close the lid. Regardless of whether I use an external monitor or not.

I read on [logind.conf](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html):
If the system is inserted in a docking station, or if more than one display is connected, the action specified by HandleLidSwitchDocked= occurs.

But setting it to suspend didn't work for me.

Comment: Check out this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When laptop lid is closed, the desktop switches to external monitor (Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1355031/when-laptop-lid-is-closed-the-desktop-switches-to-external-monitor-ubuntu-20-0)

Comment: Neither of these comments answer the OP's question, if you read them closely, at least as I can see. The question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

## All Ubuntus

Open `dconf` editor, and modify the setting:

```
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor
```

to `yes`

## Ubuntu 20.04 (logind based)

Modify `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and put value of  `HandleLidSwitchDocked` with `suspend`, ending them like:

```
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```

## Ubuntu 22.04 (Upower based)

Modify the line in `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` as follows (yes, this step sounds weird):

```
IgnoreLid=true
```

## EVERYONE

Reboot and enjoy your laptop more!

based on. https://askubuntu.com/a/1356494/170833

Answer (score 0):

`IgnoreLid=true` may no longer work in 22.04, at least it does not for me.

It's unclear to me if the commits mentioned [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/upower/upower/-/issues/246) are released or not, but the intention seems to be for upower to leave this to `systemd-logind`

See my question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1480677/make-lidswitch-suspend-with-external-monitor-connected-in-22-04).