# Make LidSwitch suspend *with* external monitor connected in 22.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, suspend, power-management

There are lots of [confusing discussions](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=HandleLidSwitchDocked) out there related to these settings in `logind.conf`

```
HandleLidSwitch
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower
HandleLidSwitchDocked
LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited
```

Most people seem to want to keep their laptops running with the lid closed when connected to an external monitor and this is now the default behavior in Ubuntu 22.04

I want the opposite, and that now seems to be impossible.
The clearest explanation I have found of how its intended to work is from Poettering himself [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7137)

My situation in short:
`HandleLidSwitch*=suspend`
`LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=true`

But gsd-power is blocking handle-lid-switch when a monitor is connected (shown by:`systemd-inhibit --list --mode=block`), and `LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=true` has no effect since this is a "low level inhibitor".

Additionally `IgnoreLid=true` in `UPower.conf` does not stop gsd-power from taking the lock and this is now [possibly](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/upower/upower/-/commit/07565ef6a1aa4a115f8ce51e259e408edbaed4cc) "as designed"

I read a suggestion somewhere that dbus could possibly be used to block upower from taking this lock, but I can find no further details of how this could be done.

All in all I would have thought this would be a quite common and reasonable behavior to want from a laptop, but now I'm stuck sideways way down this rabbit hole and I could really use some help getting out!