# How to lock pc when lid is closed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, suspend, lid

I've installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and configured all my environments, but when I was about to close my laptop lid, I encountered an issue. Instead of suspending, the external monitor continues to operate.

First, I attempted to install `gnome-tweaks`, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to resolve the problem: the relative option was already enabled, yet the issue persists. Next, I tried modifying the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file. Specifically, I commented out the following lines:

```
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```

After running `systemctl restart systemd-logind.service`, I still couldn't suspend my external monitor.

What other steps can I take to address this issue? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the System Settings then Power settings is both `On Battery power` and `When Plugged in` for When the lid is closed....  set to Suspend?

Comment: There isn't that option on my Settings > Power tab

Comment: "I commented out the following lines" ....wait, aren't those supposed to be uncommented for them to work?  If they are uncommented and still not working you more than likely have a bug.  Closing the lid should suspend the unit.  When that happens the external monitor will turn off.  If it is not, then the system is not suspending.  If you choose to suspend from the power menu and it suspends then you have a bug that is not engaging when you close the lid to the laptop.

Comment: Every line in that file started with `#`. I removed it from the line I reported. But, as previously, when I close the lid the system doesnt suspend, in fact the external monitor keeps working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out [the answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266408/configure-closing-the-lid-to-suspend-the-laptop-when-an-external-monitor-is-used#answer-1440278) and I followed **All Ubuntus** and **Ubuntu 22.04 (Upower based)** sections to solve my problem.