# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - Dual Monitor setup with closed lid

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, suspend, power-management, laptop

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 'Focal Fossa' and I want to set up my i-tec USB 3.0 Docking Station. Normally, I intend to connect my laptop (Lenovo y-700 15-isk) to the docking station, where two monitors are ready and waiting. Everything works fine when I have the lid of my laptop open. Both monitors show a picture, are responsive as expected, the system detects them correctly and I can make changes to the settings, i.e. change the order of the displays. What I want to do is close the lid and put my laptop aside while only using the two external monitors. However, when I do this the screen becomes very unresponsive and nearly unusable, i.e. 3-5 second input lag.

I have changed the power behavior such that the system will not suspend on closing the (that's why I can use my external monitors in the first place).

Does anyone have any tips or suggestions?

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, be aware the overheat problem when you closed the lid, other things might be on this. https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid