# Ubuntu 18.04: Screen not turning off or suspending when the lid is closed

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management

I hope you're well! I've been having an issue with my laptop, a Dell XPS 13 9370 running Ubuntu 18.04, where the screen does not turn off nor does the system suspend when the lid is closed. My laptop spends a lot of time in my backpack and this issue can cause the laptop to grow very hot very quickly. I've tried the solution using `systemd`, I'll paste the complete file from `systemd/logind.conf` below. However, this still isn't working for me. Does anyone have any ideas?

```sh
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details.

[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
HandleSuspendKey=suspend
HandleHibernateKey=suspend
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
#UserTasksMax=33%
```

Comment: Are you sure the hall effect sensor is working OK? Did you `systemctl restart systemd-logind` or reboot after changing that file? [`grep Lid /etc/UPower/UPower.conf`](https://askubuntu.com/a/742662/349837)?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to solve this more simply by going to menu > settings

[image]

Then select power

[image]

Then automatic suspend and set the values you want.