# How can I tell Ubuntu to only turn the screen off when I close my laptop lid?

Tags: power-management, laptop

This is closely related to this question: [How can I tell Ubuntu to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid#:%7E:text=You%20can%20easily%20disable%20the,suspend.%22%20check%2Dbox.).

I would like to stop Ubuntu from suspending or sleeping when the laptop lid is closed, while still turning the screen off to save power. How can I do that?

This is for a Dell Precision 5550 running Ubuntu 20.04 preinstalled.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using, and what brand and model of notebook are you using? Depending on the combination, it might be as simple as a single setting 

Comment: I think it’s answered here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1358045/how-do-you-disable-the-laptop-lid-switch-in-ubuntu-20-04  - whilst it says it disables the lid switch, it does turn the screen off.

Comment: @Will that solution does not work for me. It successfully stops the computer from sleeping but the screen stays on.

Comment: Your question is unclear, It needs more information like your specs, os information and what exactly you want. As it is currently written, It is hard to tell what exactly is the problem

Answer (score 4):

The answer I think is here: [Configure linux laptop to switch off screen but otherwise remain running when lid closed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248033/configure-linux-laptop-to-switch-off-screen-but-otherwise-remain-running-when-li)

The steps are

```
sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

change `#HandleLidSwitch=suspend` to `HandleLidSwitch=lock`

Then

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind.service
```

Comment: This one didn't work for me sorry

Answer (score 2):

These settings are not exposed in the Settings dialog, but can be changed with commands or using dconf Editor. Following commands will cause the computer turn off the screen when you close the lid:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'blank'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'blank'
```

As you see, you can set different actions depending on whether the computer is on AC power (`lid-close-ac-action`) or on battery power (`lid-close-battery-action`). Available actions are `blank`, `suspend`, `shutdown`, `hibernate`, `interactive`, `nothing` and `logout`.

To reset to default, specify `reset` in the command and leave out the final argument, e.g.

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have part of the answer. You do need to edit logind.conf to make sure the laptop doesn't sleep when closing the lid. The second part is you need to set the backlight to turn off after a given amount of time. Edit your /etc/default/grub. Find the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` and change it to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=consoleblank=600` or whatever timeout you like, in seconds. Don't forget to `update-grub` and reboot.

That's what I have always used, but if you specifically want to turn the screen off when you close the lid, you might also want to look here...https://mensfeld.pl/2018/08/ubuntu-18-04-disable-screen-on-lid-close/

Answer (score 0):

### Simple GUI method

Just need to install [GNOME Tweaks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tweaks) and it works well for Ubuntu

Open terminal and install gnome-tweaks and open it.

```bsh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
gnome-tweaks
```

After that you can see an option which is **Suspend when laptop lid is closed**. You just need to disable that option like below image.

[image: gnome-tweaks-menu]

Comment: Still, how to blank the screen instead?