# Don't interrupt sleep command on lid close

Tags: suspend

I have the habit of quickly setting some reminders with:

```
sleep $duration; notify-send $reminder_message
```

But lately I have had to move around and often change desks. I noticed that my `$reminder_message` started arriving later than intended. The culprit, it turn out is: that when I close lid then it suspends everything along with my `sleep` command.

Here's how I found out:

```
date; echo $duration; date -d "+$duration sec"; sleep "$duration"s; date
```

If I close my lid in between the above command then: `date` and `date -d "+$duration sec"` don't match. However if lid is not closed then they match!

So for a quick-fix I have disabled suspend with lid-close with:

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

(following [this ask-ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/372616/154488))

Now my sleep commands work as I wanted them to. But disabling suspend altogether I feel is a *too aggressive* fix and an *overkill*!

Is there a simpler solution? I just want that my `sleep` commands shouldn't be interrupted when I close my lid.

Answer (score 2):

No offense, but we may have an XY problem here. Your impression that the solution to your *real* problem is with `sleep` may be wrong. `sleep`checks until the specified time has passed, and that time stops when the computer sleeps.

Instead consider using the `at` command to schedule specific jobs to happen at a specific time.

`at` works like this:

```
echo "command_to_be_run" | at +30 minutes
```

will schedule a job 30 min later.

`at` is a lot like `cron`, but a job is run only once. It is not installed by default, but can be installed with `sudo apt install at`.

Comment: What is my second attempt? Did you mean this: `date; echo $duration; date -d "+$duration sec"; sleep "$duration"s; date`? Oh - this was just for testing. I wanted to verify the hypothesis if indeed sleep is interrupted if lid is closed. That is not my second attempt.

Comment: I had considered using `at` command at some point. But I can't recall now why I didn't like it. Let me see if I can recall and get back. If I can't I will accept your answer.

Comment: One of the issues with `at` was that I can't do `at +2 min 15 sec`. If I remember correctly, there is no support for handling duration in seconds in `at`. Is that correct? Yes - that is correct: [stackoverflow answer uses sleep with at for seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39292946/4949315)

Comment: I can't recall fully - but I had trouble with commands that need `sudo` and using it with `at`. But I am not sure if that was just me or if there was some genuine compatibility problem.

Comment: I see with respect to "second attempt": I removed that paragraph. Indeed, no seconds, but I do not see this relevant for your current use case.

Comment: Yes true. For notifications `at` works perfectly fine! But there are other places where I have used `sleep`. I didn't know `sleep` had this feature/ bug. Now it worries me what else could be breaking.

Comment: Would you know by any chance why `at` doesn't support seconds?

Comment: I did not develop it, so no. Likely because in most cases a resolution up to a single minute is plenty for practical purposes.