# How do I get Ubuntu Server to run on a lid closed laptop without hibernating?

Tags: server, laptop

I have Ubuntu Server installed on my laptop and it works fine when I leave the lid of my laptop uncovered. However, I didn't want to leave the lid of my laptop open all the time. So, I tried to put the lid on my laptop. But then, the system hibernates.

Does anyone know how I can keep Ubuntu Server in my laptop with the lid closed from hibernating?

*Sorry, my english is not very good. So some words may be strange.*

Comment: see [How can I tell Ubuntu to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably solve this by going into the BIOS/UEFI firmware and altering the system behaviour for the close the lid event. Check your laptop manual to find out how to get into the firmware settings. Typically you press F2 or the delete key while the system is early in the boot process