# 12.04-Laptop freezes everytime I close my lid

Tags: 12.04, gnome, laptop, suspend

My 12.04 Ubuntu laptop freezes every time I close my lid. I have recently installed Gnome 3.8 on my computer and removed it because I did not like it. It is probably caused because of that. And now, every time I close my lid, the only chance I have is restarting my laptop.

I just want to be able to suspend peacefully. Any help is accepted.

Comment: @Fabby Ubuntu 12.04, both desktop an server, is supported until [April 2017](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

Comment: @EricCarvalho Close vote retracted.  Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://askubuntu.com/questions/3179/closing-lid-freezes-laptop?rq=1

Comment: What graphics card do you have? Usually it's the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed Xscreensaver to get rid of this problem:

```
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-data-extra
```

then remove the gnome screen saver:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver
```

then go to the "startup applications" and press <kbd>Add</kbd> and in the command type:

```
xscreensaver -nosplash
```

In the name and description you can enter anything you want, the press <kbd>Save</kbd> and <kbd>close</kbd>

log out and log back in and problem gone!

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: Well, you shouldn't say *any help* is accepted then... ;-)  Did you restore your back-up?  Did you start *making one*??? :P

Comment: when you get back from suspend, does [Ctrl][Alt][F1] do something?  if yes, pressing [Ctrl][Alt][F7] restore everything?

Comment: i do not know about those, but ctrl + alt + F5 or F6 opens up something like terminal, would that help

Comment: @belayneh: I missed that remark (next time type @Fabby) but yes: [Ctrl][Alt][F5] is good too!

Comment: Thank you for all your help, so very much, but I managed to fix the problem( I can safely suspend now ). i managed to do this by installing `xScreensaver`. That did it all for me. And I can also Hibernate now!

Comment: I would love that