# I/O error after suspend when booting from external USB hard drive

Tags: suspend, external-hdd

I have a computer, it is an ultrabook (fujitsu UH572). This computer doesn't have any problem when installing ubuntu into internal SSD. But when I install the ubuntu 14.04.2 on an external USB 3 HDD (it is a SATA3 to USB3 HDD adapter with ASMedia chipset), and then perform a system suspend, the system suspends successfully. But if I wake up the system, the system wakes up successfully, but `dmesg` has a lot of I/O errors, and I can't load or save anything into my root partition (/), for example, when I try to save the output of dmesg to my home directory (which resides in my root partition), the command hangs and displays a lot of I/O error.

How do I enable the system to suspend correctly when I boot from the external HDD? Thank you for the asistance in advance.

Comment: Favour returned: question upvoted!  You're an 8-rep user already!  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suspending to an external HDD always works because the HDD is available when suspending.  Resuming depends on your BIOS to "wake up" devices in the correct order, so the only option you have is to upgrade your BIOS or to turn off suspension.

I got rid of this by installing the X screen saver and turning off suspend in system settings as in this answer: [12.04-Laptop freezes everytime I close my lid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575144/12-04-laptop-freezes-everytime-i-close-my-lid)